# HTML element dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I made a input number field and want to dynamic render the value of this in the container without reloading the page. I'm using ajax for this but I still have to reload the page.

HTML:

```
        <form method="post">
            <div class="main">
                <label for="numb">Parcour</label><br><br>
                <input type="number" id="numb" min="1">
            </div>
            <div class="main" style="display: block;">
                <section id="erstellen">
                    
                </section>
            </div>
        </form>
```

js:

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","dynamisch_ajax.html", true);

    xhr.onload = () => {
        if(xhr.status === 200)
        {
            $('#erstellen').html($('#numb').val())
        } else {
            alert('Irgendetwas past nicht')
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think OP uses the enter/return key to trigger submit event.

Comment: @zer00ne Well, there's a dupe for that too... [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8664486/215552) But of course, I can't vote to close again...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'll leave that to you, sir.

Comment: [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8664486/215552) But of course, I can't vote to close again... @zer00ne

Answer (score 0):

you must use from preventDefault method to prevent default refresh :

```
$("form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // The rest of the work
});
```